# Extract linestring from geometry collection

Tags: qgis, postgis

In QGIS, at SQL query intersection results in a geometrycollection column with points, linestrings and multilinestring. (first image)

I only need linestrings and multilinestring geometry to calculate the lenghts.

Using ST_CollectionìExtract I tried to select only linestring geometries but I obtain linestring empty for point geometry. (second image).

[image: Extract collection]

[image: Query intersection]

Comment: If there are no sub-geometries of the right type, an EMPTY geometry will be returned. So if you want to obtain Lines, you will get empty geometry for the points. What result do you expect to get?

Comment: A result without point. Maybe I could try to add a condizione 'WHERE ST_lenght (geom) > 0'.